# TextMate refusing to launch in Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, textmate, launching

I found [this post](http://thelucid.com/2011/11/24/textmate-refusing-to-launch-in-lion/) useful and important to share, so if anybody has problems running textmate after updating to OSX lion, do as follows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[from http://thelucid.com/2011/11/24/textmate-refusing-to-launch-in-lion/]:***

On occasion under OSX Lion, TextMate refuses to launch. I’ve found that simply deleting it’s pid file seems to get things working again, just open Terminal and type:

```
rm ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/TextMate.pid
```